EditForm .net 8 bind value not workin in login page
this is my app.razor:
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account") ? null : InteractiveServer;
}

And this is my login page:
@page "/Account/Login"

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject ILogger<Login> Logger
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Se connecter</PageTitle>

<h1>Se connecter</h1>

@if (errorMessage != null)
{
    <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Error">@errorMessage</MudAlert>
}
<MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Small">
    <MudCard>
        <EditForm Model="Input" OnValidSubmit="LogInUser" FormName="SignInUserForm">
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudTextField @bind-Value="Input.Email"
                              For="@(() => Input.Email)"
                              Immediate="true"
                              Label="Courriel" />

                <MudTextField @bind-Value="Input.Password"
                              For="@(() => Input.Password)"
                              Immediate="true"
                              Label="Mot de passe"
                              InputType="InputType.Password" />
            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                @if (InProgress)
                {
                    <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Primary" Indeterminate="true" Class="ml-auto" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto" ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit">Se connecter</MudButton>
                }
            </MudCardActions>
        </EditForm>
    </MudCard>
</MudContainer>

@code {
    private string? errorMessage = null;
    private bool InProgress = false;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;
    
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (HttpMethods.IsGet(HttpContext.Request.Method))
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
        }
    }

    public async Task LogInUser()
    {
        InProgress = true;
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("L'utilisateur est connecté.");
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Home");
        }
        else if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning("Le compte a été bloqué.");
            errorMessage = "Le compte a été bloqué.";
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Erreur: tentative de connexion invalide.";
        }
        InProgress = false;
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le courriel ne doit pas être vide.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Ceci n'est pas une adresse courriel valide.")]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le mot de passe ne doit pas être vide.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    }
}

So when I populate the field, the Input model is still string empty. I cannot put Interactive Mode for rendering because HttpContext is not working then. Do you know what can I Do?
So maybe there is a render mode that I don't know or something to write that I missed?

Edit as follows:
private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account/Login") ? null : InteractiveServer;

